# Is there a way to have a white background on transparent PNGs in Picasa?

Tags: macos, picasa

Is there a way to have a white background  on transparent PNGs in Picasa? I generally shows a background of black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some google search looks like changing background color is a often requested feature, but not yet available.